# How to set a quantifier to prevent intermediate terms from evaporating in ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

The following code worked until I converted to ARC.  It fails now because vcObj contains a nil after the line executes.

```
[[self vcPhoto] setVcObj: [NSClassFromString( [[self vcPhoto] vcClassName] ) new]];
```

I've experimented and if I change the code like so, it works again and the object x is assigned to vcObj as expected:

```
id x = [NSClassFromString( [[self vcPhoto] vcClassName] ) new]];
[[self vcPhoto] setVcObj: x];
```

It seems to me that the class generated from:

```
[NSClassFromString( [[self vcPhoto] vcClassName] ) new]
```

Is immediately evaporating before it can be assigned to vcObj.

I've read "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes" and especially the part on variable qualifiers but I cannot see how to mark the intermediate so it will survive until it is consumed.

Comment: Break it down into single steps and walk through it with the debugger. `id vcp = [self vcPhoto]; id cname = [vcp vcClassName]; ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `vcObj` property defined as `weak` or `assign`? It should be `strong` in order to retain the passed value.

Comment: Bingo, Leo.  Thanks.   As soon as I set vcObj to strong, it worked as expected.